# how to clear the entire stdout?

Tags: python, stdout

I want to print some strings in more than one line and then clear it and overwrite some other strings in stdout.

I know about `\r` to return and overwrite the current line, but I want to clear every lines in stdout.

and I also know about `os.system('clear')` to clear the screan but I don't want to clear the whole screen because it clears everything including the commands has been run before running this script and shell statuses.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus no! I want to do it in python and I don't want to use system clear command as I explicitly explained it

Comment: You could store the stuff you don't want deleted and then clear the screen with `os.system('clear')` and then reprint what was already there. That might be a possibility but I don't know how your program is setup so maybe not

Comment: @mehdy: I'm sorry, I don't know why I thought it's C++ question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to use the [curses](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) package for this sort of thing.

Comment: Which of the hundreds of functions in the package?